# Importing, moving, rotating and scaling jpg images onto OSM maps in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing, scale, rotate

I'm a master planner and I want to use QGIS for, among others, importing images (jpg, png, etc without any georeferences). These images will mostly be screenshots of existing structures in Google Earth.

Now when I import such an image the scale and location are far off to what and where I want it. Does anyone know a good method to insert the image on the wanted location on the OSM base layer, translate, rotate and proportionally scale it?

Comment: See [georeferencing basics](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html)

Comment: See our [Self-assembling FAQ on Georeferencing in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/georeferencing+qgis?sort=frequent).

Comment: The accuracy that is reached by using georeferencing is nice, but I want to be able to move and rotate a (georeferenced) layer by preferably dragging it over the screen.

Answer (score 7):

Since your images are without any georeferences, you can use this QGIS plugin named: *[Freehand raster georeferencer](http://gvellut.github.io/FreehandRasterGeoreferencer/)*

In QGIS, open the "Plugins" > "Manage and install plugin" dialog. Install the "Freehand raster georeferencer" plugin.

[image]

After installing it, its icons should be added to your tool bar.

[image]

If you don't see the icons on your tool bar, go to Raster >> Freehand Raster Georeferencer

[image]

Use the button labeled with "AD" to add your raster images, move them using "MO", rotate using "RO", scale using "SC", etc. The plugin works on both QGIS version 2 and 3, see more about using it on the [plugin page](http://gvellut.github.io/FreehandRasterGeoreferencer/).

Comment: Worked great for my purposes, but just as a heads up, the "2P" function to georeference an image by two points appears to be broken in QGIS 3.8.

Answer (score 3):

The world file format is the way to spatial reference images. This file usually has the same name as you raster file but use another extension (*.w, *.wld or *.jgw, *.pgw etc).
This is a text file with 6 lines:

```
20.0000000000000 A
0.00000000000000 B
0.00000000000000 C
-20.000000000000 D
424178.117       E
4313415.907      F
```

This values correspondent to formula:

```
x1 = Ax + Сy + E
y1 = Dx + By + F
```

**A** and **D** is pixel size in your Spatial Reference values (meters, degrees, etc)

**E** and **F** are upper left corner coordinates of your image

**B** and **C** - rotation

QGIS accepts this format (don't forget *.prj file with your projection WKT)

Some details is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file

Answer (score 2):

There are some cases we cannot easily create reliable GCPs (ground control points) to georeference our image onto target layer.

I usually use [Freehand raster georeferencer](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/FreehandRasterGeoreferencer/) to interactively insert such images on my map.

It works like adding an Image Overlay on GoogleEarth.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this plugin. For me the large downside of the plugin is that you cannot scale proportionally and therefore mess up the image.

I am looking for such a tool though, since georeferencing (as described in the earlier anwers) is a bit too much into detail for my specific use of qgis.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily through the [Georeferencer](https://sites.google.com/a/wisc.edu/wiscsims-micro-qgis/learn-to-use-qgis/map-creation-basics/importing-and-georeferencing-an-image) tool available on QGIS (3.16.9).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).